# Segmentation fault in C++ before entering main

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, g++, program-entry-point

This is quite common question and I tried reading the solutions but none of them seem to fix my problem. Here is the code I wrote which I know is quite a mess because I am a newbie at C++.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<set>
#include<queue>
#include<cmath>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<limits.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<map>
#include<cstring>
using ll = long long;
const int N = 2e6+6;

int main(){
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    std::cin.tie(0);
    int n,m;
    std::cin >> n >> m;
    std::vector<std::array<int,3>> edges;
    int exist[n][n];
    memset(exist,0,sizeof(exist));
    for(int i = 0; i < m;++i){
        int a,b;
        char c;
        std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
        --a,--b;
        edges.push_back({a,b,c-'a'});
        exist[a][b] = exist[b][a] = 1;
    }
    std::vector<int> adj[N];
    std::map<std::pair<int,int>,int> nodes;
    int node = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < m;++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < m;++j){
            if(i == j)
                continue;
            if(edges[i][2] != edges[j][2])
                continue;
            int a = edges[i][0];
            int b = edges[i][1];
            int c = edges[j][0];
            int d = edges[j][1];
            if(nodes[{a,c}] == 0)
                nodes[{a,c}] = ++node;
            if(nodes[{b,d}] == 0)
                nodes[{b,d}] = ++node;
            if(nodes[{a,d}] == 0)
                nodes[{a,d}] = ++node;
            if(nodes[{b,c}] == 0)
                nodes[{b,c}] = ++node;
            adj[nodes[{a,c}]].push_back(nodes[{b,d}]);
            adj[nodes[{b,d}]].push_back(nodes[{a,c}]);
            adj[nodes[{a,d}]].push_back(nodes[{b,c}]);
            adj[nodes[{b,c}]].push_back(nodes[{a,d}]);
        }
    }
    int start = nodes[{0,n-1}];
    int ans = 1e9+7;
    std::queue<int> q;
    q.push(start);
    std::vector<int> dist(node+1,-1);
    dist[start] = 0;
    std::vector<bool> visited(node+1,false);
    visited[start] = true;
    auto it = nodes.begin();
    while(!q.empty()){
        int cur_node = q.front();
        q.pop();
        for(int i = 0; i < (int)adj[cur_node].size();++i){
            int next_node = adj[cur_node][i];
            if(!visited[next_node]){
                q.push(next_node);
                visited[next_node] = true;
                dist[next_node] = dist[cur_node] + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n;++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < n;++j){
            int node = nodes[{i,j}];
            if(node == 0)
                continue;
            if(dist[node] == -1)
                continue;
            if(i == j || (exist[i][j] == 1)){
                ans = std::min(ans,dist[node]);
            }
        }
    }
    if(ans == 1e9+7)
        ans = -1;
    std::cout << ans << "\n";
}
```

This program gives segmentation fault even before entering main and I tried using gdb which also says that error is on the line `int main()` . I don't understand at all what is happening, and also I tried running the program on C++ 14 and C++ 17 and it runs fine but I am using C++ 11 and it compiles successfully but doesn't run. Please help me.

Comment: I stopped reading at `using ll = long long;`. Also, What do you think the first two lines do?

Comment: do you mean, the first two lines after main? They are supposed to turn of the sync between C++ i/o and C i/o right?

Comment: I kinda like doing it as I can enter all my input at once and then get the output together which makes it much convenient for me to check my solution . Also, I do competitive programming (ok don't start please) so well it helps for large inputs it seems.

Comment: because when I remove them, i get the output as soon as i give the input when I have inputs for multiple test cases. Yea, here it seems its not needed though maybe

Comment: so, those two lines are the problem? and why?

Comment: No, I meant for multiple test cases. If I say enter input for one test case, without those two lines, I will get the output and then I can enter input for next test case but with those two lines, I can just enter all the input at once and then get the collective output .Yes, I tried gdb , it says error at the `int main(), line 16`

Comment: You’re trying to allocate over 2 million `std::vector`s in stack. Why? That will easily cause a problem.

Comment: `int exist[n][n]` - [C++ doesn't support VLAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). Moreover, you need to include `<array>` and `<vector>` to use `std::array` and `std::vector`. I am not sure how your compiler compiled all that without giving a single error...

Comment: yea, I forgot, I added the include for array now. how did it not give error? also, where am I allocating those 2 million vectors? @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: `std::vector<int> adj[N]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re allocating over two million `std::vector`s in your code in stack. Usually the stack isn’t very big so that most definitely will go over the reserved space and cause issues. The allocation for local objects happens before any code in the function is run so it will look like it crashes in the function but before any of your code is run.

```
std::vector<int> adj[N];
```

You’ll need to allocate it dynamically if you need that many vectors.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is not valid C++:

```
int n;
cin >> n;
int exist[n][n];  // <-- not valid C++
```

Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a compile-time expression, not a runtime value.  [C++ does not support variable-length arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard).

The code compiled, since there are some compilers that by default, have support for this.  But it still is not supported by the C++ language specification.  For example, the Visual C++ compiler does not support this syntax.  If you attempted to compile your code using Visual C++, you would be greeted with the appropriate error message.

Even if this is supported, a large value of `n` could potentially blow the stack memory, since the stack memory is limited.

Then the second issue is that you have this:

`std::vector<int> adj[N];`

If `N` is large, that is an array of `N` `std::vector<int>`.  Again, this will more than likely exhaust the stack memory.

---

One solution is to use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> exist(n, std::vector<int>(n));
//...
std::vector<std::vector<int>> adj(N):
```

Since the vector gets its memory from the heap, the stack memory exhaustion issue goes away.

Comment: Thanks for this . I myself prefer vectors but the problem was that declaring multidimensional vectors is much harder than arrays. Also, I realised it today after 1 year of C++, that syntax I have been using was wrong. I was getting lucky.I wonder if some easier way of declaring multidimensional vectors exist .